# Key-Value pairs in ASP.NET - Clientside

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, visual-studio-2012

I am very new to writing ASP.NET web apps..but i've been tasked with doing so.  I have an extensive set of web services i've written that work with our backend databases.  Up until now, i've written solely desktop apps using these web services.  this is my first venture into web applications.

So far i've been doing quite well.  But i've come to a point where i'm trying to minimize some postback delays.

I'm using a gridview to have users enter some data for a one-to-many relationship.  One of the fields they select from a dropdown list.  After selecting this list, i was doing a postback to get the corresponding key value and then displaying it but this took to long.  Ideally, this should be instantaneous, so i was wondering what the best approach would be - clientside/javascript - to do a lookup on a list of name-value pairs?

From some preliminary web searching, it appears the two most popular approaches would be to use either a hidden field to store the lists, or to store it in a JSON object?

I'm looking for opinions on the best approach, and how specifically to store this list on the client side?  From what i understand, using a hidden field could be the easiest.

Opinions?

Comment: either of the solutions you mention are fine.

Comment: JSON is better suited to a key-value list.

Comment: You tagged your question with devexpress, are you using DevEx ASPxGridView or ASP.NET gridview?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to store it at all on the client side but rather do an async Ajax call to the server to retrieve the actual value.  You should be able to accomplish this easily by putting the GridView and the displayed label controls into an UpdatePanel where the Trigger is defined as your dropdown list.

Comment: Just to clarify - the dropdown is part of the gridview.  I changed a column type via a template approach.

Comment: I think it can still work but can be complicated to implement as you have to make sure the onchange of the dropdownlist will call the update trigger of the UpdatePanel.